# polygon tessellation in opengl shader

Tags: opengl, shader

I want 20k+ 2D polygons to be rendered in opengl with outline & fill.

Some polygons are concave.

Is it possible to do this using shaders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need shaders for this:

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL); //Fill
glDrawElements(...);
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE); //Outline
glDrawElements(...);
```

If the polygons are concave you'll have to tesselate them, either manually or using the gl utility library, glu. Look at `gluNewTess`. If you decide to tesselate the polygons yourself you'll have to remember to set the correct edge flags so that the interior edges of the tesselation aren't rendered, see `glEdgeFlagPointer`.

**EDIT:** I found the following [link](http://zrusin.blogspot.com/2006/07/hardware-accelerated-polygon-rendering.html) on how to use the stencil buffer to render concave polygons.

Comment: if some polygons are concave?

Comment: thanks! will try. but still, tessellation has to be done on CPU, not using a shader?

Comment: @madcat Generally yes, it may be possible to do on the GPU in future versions of geometry shaders but I don't *think* it's possible right now. However, I found an interesting way of rendering concave polygons using the stencil buffer, see update.

Comment: The stencil method is somewhat better explained here: http://fly.srk.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/chapter13.html (search for concave). It involves drawing the polygon as a triangle fan twice, first to generate the stencil buffer, second to draw where the stencil was set.

Comment: `gluNewTess` is now deprecated, what's the modern way of achieving this?